# How to open Reactjs MUI DatePicker popup when click inside it to edit date without using openPickerButton?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Currently, DatePicker shows a calendar icon to open the calendar popup. I can remove the icon with disableOpenPicker prop but I want to open the popup when the user clicks the Datepicker input field and it should work exactly the same as with the opener icon.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2gMV.png)

Answer (score 4):

#### With Mui Date Picker V6

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

```html
<DatePicker
  open={isOpen}
  onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      onClick: () => setIsOpen(true)
    }
  }}
  slots={{
    openPickerButton: () => null
  }}
/>
```

#### Part 1

It's to make the entire field clickable, and open/close the picker.

```js
open={isOpen}
onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
slotProps={{
  textField: {
    onClick: () => setIsOpen(true)
  }
}}
/>
```

#### Part 2

It's to hide the calendar icon button

```js
slots={{
  openPickerButton: () => null
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`disableOpenPicker` prop will not just remove the icon, but also disable the picker. You will still have the input field with date validation. You can replace or hide the icon using `openPickerIcon` to set an icon of your choice.
Alternatively, you can use `MobileDatePicker` if you don't want to configure anything. MobileDatePicker will give you an input field which opens a picker on click.

See Mobile Picker here - https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/
API Reference - https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use Mobile Picker as a requirement. I want the functionality applied to the whole field without a button.

Answer (score 0):

It's my solution to custom `input` Date Textbox, add event onClick `handleOpenPopUp` and add `open` props to DatePicker. You can see detail [here](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/)

```
 <DatePicker
    ...
    open={open}
    renderInput={...}
/>
```

```js
renderInput={({ inputRef, inputProps, InputProps }) => {
return (
  <Box
    className="form-calendar"
    sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
  >
    <input
      className="form-control"
        ref={inputRef}
        {...inputProps}
        value={moment(acceptedDate).format("L")}
        readOnly
        onClick={handleOpenPopUp}
      />
      {InputProps?.endAdornment}
  </Box>
  );
}}
```